# Can I use angularjs based (angular-footballdata-api-factory) in angular2 app?

Tags: api, angular, angular-factory

I hava got an angularjs based [api-factory](https://github.com/JohnnyTheTank/angular-footballdata-api-factory) 
I want to use this in angular2 app. Is it possible to use it and if yes, then how.

Answer (score 0):

No, Angular 2 is not a superset of Angular 1 -- it's a different API.

Therefore you cannot use libraries from Angular 1.x on an Angular 2.x application.

Comment: is there a way to change these APIs to make it compatible with angular2

Comment: @NitishKumar you would have to rewrite it.